# How can I extract a javascript variable from html content using xpath?

Tags: xpath

I am stuck with the following sample html content: It's a little trickier than I thought.

```
<div id="map-control">
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var extStreetviewControl = null;
    var pano = null;
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng('56.18497', '10.21306');
    var noFlash = false;
    var noStreetView = false;

</script>
```

I need to extract the coordinate values `var point` . I figured regex would do the trick. But I don't know how to proceed. How can I achieve that using xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Your html is marlformed (missing the closing `<div>`), but try something like

```
substring-after(//script[2], 'var point = ')
```